# Один блок на всех страницах. (На метки не смотреть, т.к. я не знаю какие яыки)

Tags: php, iframe

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы один блок например меню на сайте, не надо было вставлять на каждом сайте, а просто новый файл создаешь в него забиваешь на пример только "<h1>Контент</h1>", а когда заходишь на страницу там уже есть меню. на движке DataLifeEnginer такое есть, но мне без движка надо, а просто файлы с этой фигней. Мне кажется это делается через IFrame, но врядле.

```
Напишите пожалуйста через что это делается и как.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте, если чисто html, то можно через фреймы. Если это сервер с поддержкой php, можно include, file_get_contents... Также через javascript можно сделать, все зависит от вашего желания